# Objective-c use CharacterAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, indexing, character

I want to use `characterAtIndex` in Objective-C to compare the character at a certain position and a character ('v' for example). The problem is that `characterAtIndex` seems to send an int and not a character. I tried to do something like this:

```
if ([string characterAtIndex:i] = @"v")
```

or also:

```
if (string[[string characterAtIndex:i]] .... )
```

I know that in some language you can go directly to a certain position in the string (like an array) to see the character, but it doesn't seems to work that way in Objective-C.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`characterAtIndex` returns a char, not NSString object, so do this kind of thing instead,

```
if ([a characterAtIndex:i] == 'v')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought that 'v' and "v" were the same.

Answer (score 4):

I like @X-Slash's answer better (+1), but to be thorough I'll show how you would do this with only OOP cocoa (that is, with NSString's instead of c-strings).

```
if([[a substringWithRange:(NSRange){0,1}] isEqualToString:@"v"]) { ...
```

Where {0,1} is the first character, {1,1} is the second, etc.

Comment: Very helpful in extracting individual characters from another language such as Japanese, as `characterAtIndex:` does not work for this